# Dumb completion in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, autocomplete

Intellisense is nice for what it does, but often I find myself longing for the "crude" text completion of editors like Vim. I can't seem to find a facility for being able to complete a word--perhaps in a string, anywhere really--and have VS try to complete it for me (based on stuff I've typed before in the current buffer, or in all open files, or however it wants to work).

Am I missing something? (Or if necessary, is there an extension to do this?) It seems like it would actually be tons easier to implement than Intellisense, but it really can save typing.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea. I sometimes find myself entering near-identical long string literals, and something like this would be easier than copy/paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to look at the [VisualAssist](http://wholetomato.com/) add-in. Its autocomplete is aware of the things you typed recently, so it selects the most recent match by default. It also works in more places than the standard IntelliSense (e.g. include paths).

A word of warning however, when you start using it, it's hard to go back...

Comment: cannot find out how to auto complete string literals, am I missing something?

Comment: @VincentXue: As far as I know, Visual Assist will not auto-complete string literals **except** include paths.

Comment: A nice tool, I used it but now I use Jetbrains.  They're both horrifically slow behemoths wrapped around CLANG/LLVM and now Jetbrains has decided it will **also** support Unreal Engine, just like the above.  Of course it makes more sense to compete in the same niche market as your only competitor, rather than attempt to differentiate yourself by actually becoming more useful.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2010 implementing intellisense is extremely easy - assuming that you have a ready answer for 2 questions:

1. What should trigger the dialog
2. What is the list of possible completions for the current word.

In my custom editor I spent 90% of time on making the NDjango parser give to me what I need and only 10% on actually "implementing" intellisense

**Edit**

The project s open source feel free to [download](http://www.hill30.com/MikeFeingoldBlog/index.php/2009/07/29/django-editor-in-vs-2010-part-0-background/) the code and play with it.

Comment: Fair enough, but this really shouldn't need to involve intellisense at all. That is, I don't need "code completion," just simple text completion based on words I've typed previously so I don't need to type them again. (Also note that this must be available in addition to standard intellisense; I'm not looking to replace code completion altogether.)

Comment: I understand what you want, and I do not know whether anything of the sort is already out there, What I am trying to say is it would be pretty easy to implement your own version, including the very valid point of your code completion complementing (not replacing) the existing one(s). The point here is no matter how easy and obvious 'text completion' sounds to you, the next person will have his own idea on how it has to work

Comment: You'd still need to hook up into editor's IntelliSense APIs because that's what provides the completion list etc... but making it list all other words in the buffer is fairly trivial. Especially if you target VS2010 with its much saner new editor extensibility APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/), Vi/vim emulation for Visual Studio, Word, Outlook and SQL Server. If it still doesn't fulfill your needs, attempt at rolling your own. Check out the [Visual Studio Extensibility Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) and [this tutorial](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0710082) to help you get started on VS Add-Ins.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers, Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 has become much better. Not only the extensibility, but also implementation.

It now filters the list of members containing the typed name anywhere within them. This also works with classes and types, so you don't have to remember the full type or class name. And last be not least, you can filter the list using the Pascal Case naming pattern. This means less typing and less mistyping.

More information on the Intellisense improvements in VS2010 can be found on [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/22/vs-2010-code-intellisense-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) show suggestions for completion of words in strings or everywhere else. They have a free version, but i don't know if it supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The extensibility model in 2010 is much simpler but is (obviously) still a moving target.

It should be possible to get something simple using [the intellisense part of this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense%28VS.100%29.aspx)
 to supply an [ICompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.icompletionsource_members%28VS.100%29.aspx) which merges in whatever values you want to supply along with the existing implementations results.

Monitoring the current buffer for names should involve some playing around with the [ITextView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview_properties%28VS.100%29.aspx) and [ITextBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextbuffer%28VS.100%29.aspx).

There is an example of modifying the [presentation layer](http://editorsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Intellisense%20Presenter%20Implementation&referringTitle=IntelliSense%20Presenter) on codeplex but you should be able to use that as a base on which to try altering the data side of things.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) from Jetbrains also has completion that is very intelligent.  CTRL+SHFIT+Space activates their "intelligent" code completion (beyond your normal CTRL+Space results), which is type and context-sensitive.  I frequently find it is choosing appropriate names for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a handful of words you are looking to fill in, you can easily create some snippets to do that.

It's more than a bit of a hack, but it might be helpful.

Snippet xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>retype</Title>
      <Shortcut>retype</Shortcut>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[ThisIsTheTextIHateToRetype();$end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Please, no... stop it... you're making me laugh.  It's 2 days before 2021 and there is still no **snippet** engine worth the name available for MSVC.  No matter what you're willing to spend, you cannot get the basic functionality of TextMate, UltiSnips, or any kind of user-definable **postfix** snippet capability, i.e. `MyVarThatIForgotToPrefaceWithAn.if` *<tab>* becomes `if (MyVar...) { <cursor> }`.  Jetbrains can do it in MSVC, but if you're not writing in C# you have to **lodge a written request** to have your postfix snippet added.